# How do I write the following as a regular expression to replace multiple occurances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

#### Background:

I have string of html with about 10 image tags that passes through some JavaScript as a string at runtime before being injected into a containing element.  The `data-thumb` tag of each image is slightly incorrect and needs to be altered before making it into the DOM.  Here is an example:

```
<img src="foo_lg_db.jpg" data-large="foo_lg_db.jpg" />
<img src="bar_lg_db.jpg" data-large="bar_lg_db.jpg" />
<img src="fizz_lg_db.jpg" data-large="fizz_lg_db.jpg" />
```

Needs to become:

```
<img src="foo_tn_db.jpg" data-large="foo_lg_db.jpg" />
<img src="bar_tn_db.jpg" data-large="bar_lg_db.jpg" />
<img src="fizz_tn_db.jpg" data-large="fizz_lg_db.jpg" />
```

#### Question:

In JavaScript (jQuery is OK), how do I achieve this search and replace?

#### THE ANSWER:

Thanks to Mark's answer I learned that it is possible to instantiate a jQuery object before it hits the DOM so, rather than using `regex`, I did something like this:

```
var stringHtml = "<img . . .";
var div = $("<div>").html(stringHtml );
$.each(div.find('img[src]'), function () {
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_lg', ''));
});

return div.html();
```

Comment: If this is all a string, does it contain stuff that would prevent you from simply doing a string replacement of `_lg_db` to `_tn_db`?

Comment: Yes there something preventing my doing that--I need to maintain the "_lg_db"  in the `data-large` attribute but change it in the `src` attribute.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('img[data-thumb]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data-thumb', $(this).attr('data-thumb').replace('_lg_','_tn_'));
});
```

Something like that in jQuery.

Sounds like a problem you should be fixing server-side if possible though.

---

If you give jQuery an HTML element like `$('<div>')` it will essentially create the HTML element for you and then you can manipulate it before inserting it  into your DOM. I don't know if it will handle multiple elements, but you can create a container first (like above) and then set the content like so

```
$('<div>').html(yourHtml).find('img[data-thumb'])./* code above */
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, but this code needs to execute on the 'string' of html before hitting the DOM and I would think that means I cant use jQuery selectors on it.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can also pass a function to `.attr` so as to make it more concise: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: Ah..you said "jQuery is OK" so I assumed you actually had a DOM to work with.

Comment: Agree that this should be fixed server side but that is not possible in this case with out a great deal of work (long story).  Thank for your help though.  If you happen to know how to work the `regex` magic that would be a huge help.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: Why can't you insert into the DOM first, and then "fix" it right away?

Comment: @Mark--I *can* do that, but would rather not because it starts loading these enormous image files into tiny (20px X 20px) thumbnails and their is a lag as they load.  In writing this I am realizing that my example is reversed it should be the thumbnails that load in `src` and the large file path in `data-large`.  I will correct.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt: See my update. You don't actually have to put it into your DOM before you can start manipulating it. I'm hesitant to recommend a regex [because](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/65387)

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I got it working.  I did not know that you could instantiate a jQuery object before it is in the DOM!